# Why can't I remove an item?

Tags: java, android, arrays, database, string

I am really frustrated because I have been trying this for 4 hours today, and I can't find a solution. For some reason, my on long click listener doesn't get detected sometimes!

```
 listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int pos, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Long click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            contactArrayList.remove(pos);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            return true;
        }
    });
```

This simple code just removes an item from my list and my array list using an adapter. But, sometimes, **the onItemLongClickListener doesn't even get called, and the toast doesn't even display!!** I know that android is detecting it, because I get this message whenever I long click in my log cat:

```
/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
```

So why does it only work sometimes? Is there something wrong with my code, or is this a problem with android itself? If it is a problem with android, how can I fix it?

**It works the first time, but after exiting my app, rotating the screen, etc. , Long press stops getting detected. I have been stuck on this for almost 8 hours now, and I really, really, really need your help.**

Comment: I don't know if this is releated, but I also got this message: `Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected! Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@RANDOMNUMBERSANDLETTERS)`

Comment: Also, for example it will work, then I will rotate the screen, and it will stop working...

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the code posted. Checking your stacktrace and checking for memory leaks might help find the cause

Comment: @Rich, I have few questions, in which method you are registering for listener, is any condition applied for setting listener. If it is got fixed please ignore this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OnItemCLickListener not working in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551042/onitemclicklistener-not-working-in-listview)

Answer (score 0):

May be try using View.OnItemLongClickListener() instead of AdapterView and change the parameter in OnItemLongClick() to View.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're actually removing the item from the array inside the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your listener gets destroyed during a config change, or does not always get initialized. Make sure the code block which setting the listener is part of gets called each time.