# OnItemClickListener does not work with CheckBoxes

Tags: java, android

I've already checked the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900913/onitemclicklistener-was-not-work-with-the-checkbox), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367936/listview-onitemclicklistener-not-responding), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367936/listview-onitemclicklistener-not-responding/4518810#4518810) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108940/why-cant-i-remove-an-item/35109304#35109304). None of them works for me.

My problem is as follows:
I've a ListView consists of just CheckBoxes. I would like to save the current status of the relevant CheckBox to the SharedPreferences as soon as the CheckBox is clicked, as checked or unchecked. But I cannot do so yet. I've already tried OnItemClickListener in Activity's onCreate method and then OnClickListener in Adapter's getView method. I don't know if somethings conflict with eachother.

Here is My Activity's onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food);


    foodItems = new ArrayList<>();
    foodItems.add(new FoodItem("Fridge and Stove", fridgeKey));
    foodItems.add(new FoodItem("Baked Alaska", bakedAlaskaKey));
    ...

    ListView foodListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.food_list_view);
    foodListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    FoodItemAdapter foodItemAdapter = new FoodItemAdapter(this, foodItems);
    foodListView.setAdapter(foodItemAdapter);
}
```

Here is current status of my adapter (I've tried this and that):

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View foodItemView = convertView;
    if (foodItemView == null) {
        foodItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_food, parent, false);
    }
    final FoodItem currentFoodItem = getItem(position);
    final CheckBox foodCheckBox = (CheckBox) foodItemView.findViewById(R.id.item_food_check_box);
    foodCheckBox.setText(currentFoodItem.getText());
    Boolean status = getStatus(currentFoodItem.getPrefsKey());
    foodCheckBox.setChecked(status);
    Log.i("Food Item Adapter", "get view");

    foodItemView.setClickable(true);
    foodItemView.setFocusable(true);
    foodItemView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.menuitem_background);
    foodItemView.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i("Food Item Adapter", "on click");
                    SharedPreferences prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences("com.example.myapplication", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    prefs.edit().putBoolean(currentFoodItem.getPrefsKey(), foodCheckBox.isChecked()).apply();
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).setTitle("touched").show();
                }
    });

    return foodItemView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
final CheckBox foodCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.item_food_check_box);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    foodCheckBox.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean("checked",false));

foodCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
         isCheckedValue = isChecked;
        editor.putBoolean("checked", isChecked);
        editor.apply();
        }
    });
```

You can use value in `isCheckedValue` to send anywhere you need.

And then if you want to send this value to any of the activity you can use below code

```
 Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntendedActivity.class);
                in.putExtra("yourBoolName", isCheckedValue );
                startActivity(in);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this attribute to your list item layout:

```
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
```

This will allow the children of the list item to draw focus.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried it. Not working, unfortunately.