# Why isn't my onitemlongclick listener working?

Tags: android, android-studio, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener, onitemlongclicklistener

From MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {
    private DataSourceSql mDataSourceSql;
    protected ArrayList<String> mProfileNames;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDataSourceSql = new DataSourceSql(MainActivity.this);
        mNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        //this part here
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setLongClickable(true);
    }
```

The id of the `ListView` in this case is set in the XML as `android:id="@android:id/list"`.

And then later on in the same activity:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Toast.makeText(this, mNames.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, final int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "long clicked: " + mNames.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
}
```

But when I long-press an item in the list, the only thing that triggers is `onListItemClick`. I never get the message with the long click.

Comment: I assume long click = press and hold (I want to be able to hold an item in a list and get more options)

Comment: You need to call `lv.setOnLongClickListener(this)`.

Comment: @MikeM. Is my answer wrong / bad practice?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6703671/3790150

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20932220/3790150  try this

Comment: @MikeM. So in other words I can just keep what I have in the OP and add the line `lv.setOnLongClickListener(this)`?

Comment: @MikeM. I do that during an updateList method that I call during onResume and after I finish a function that inserts new items into the db that powers the list.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't implement an interface like AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener directly in your onCreate().. Just use your old way (Your class implement this interface) and with each method override, you have to write like this:

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
lv.setonListItemLongClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, but someone please correct me if I'm missing something.

I removed the "implements..." thing and then added the following to the onCreate method:

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener
                () {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int
                    pos, long id) {
                onListItemLongClick(v, pos, id);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Although I am not sure if I should be returning true or false there.

I also changed the long click function down below to

```
public boolean onListItemLongClick(View v, final int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "long clicked: " + mNames.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
}
```

Edit:

Quicker approach is to just add `lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);` to my onCreate method in the OP.

Comment: If your `Activity` implements `OnItemLongClickListener` interface then you simply call `lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);`

Answer (score 0):

Use This. Your Problem will Solve.

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Long Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```